# Undefined offset: 2 and Undefined offset: 1 and Uninitialized string offset: 0

Tags: php

getting the notice error for array how to resolve this unintialized string and undefined offset.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($exp_company);$i++)
{
    $exp_fd2 = explode("/",$exp_fd1 [$i]);
    $exp_td2 = explode("/",$exp_td1 [$i]);
    $exp_fd = $exp_fd2[2]."-".$exp_fd2[1]."-".$exp_fd2[0];
    $exp_td = $exp_td2[2]."-".$exp_td2[1]."-".$exp_td2[0];
   mysql_query("insert into empexp(employee_id,company_name,designation,from_date,to_date,exp_description)values('$insert_id','$exp_company[$i]','$exp_designation[$i]','$exp_fd','$exp_td','$exp_description[$i]')");
}
```

Comment: What's the issue here? The error is quite clear about the problem

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\paydocs_ui\mainsave.php on line 143

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\paydocs_ui\mainsave.php on line 146

Comment: @Martin how to stop getting those notice errors..i have been trying a lot couldnt find the solution

Comment: Welcome on SO. What you have posted is not a question. Please have a look at the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide to we'll be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here You are Trying to Access the index which does not exist.

undefined offset means that an array has run out of bounds as simple as that.

let's assume your array is:

[0]==> 'a',
[1]==> 'b',

From above I cannot access array[2] as it does not exist.

the array size is smaller than the index that you are trying to fetch.